# Eclipse generic language support template

Tags: eclipse

I have to implement support in Eclipse for a few different languages. I feel some pain that starting up with the projects is a lot of boilerplate. I can't use Xtext and DLTK was not very friendly last I tried it. Is there any project template for setting up all the required extensions and classes and configuration? If not, is there a need for one or is it just me?

Thanks in advance. 
Vlad